# In Objective C, why use `self == [className self]` in a class +initialize?

Tags: objective-c

I've seen this in an example-- In a class initialize, does this line have any purpose?

```
+(void)initialize
{
   if (self == [ToolController self])
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

I have read that in a class method, self refers to the class and not an object.  So in theory, wouldn't this check always result in true?

In my mind, that line would resolve to this:
`ToolController == ToolController`

So that's why I would think that it would always result in true.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What would happen if there was a subclass of `ToolController`?

Comment: I am pretty sure the reason is given in the docs fot initialize.

Comment: The "duplicate" question is not a duplicate question. It's a slightly related question that happens to have the same answer. Duplicate questions should actually ask the same question, not just have similar answers.

Comment: Here's a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324666/should-initialize-load-always-start-with-an-if-self-myclass-class-guar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the possibility that `self` is a *subclass* of ToolController.

Presumably in the example you're reading, whatever is happening in `+[ToolController initialize]` should happen only when the superclass (`ToolController`) initializes, and not happen *additionally* when any subclasses of `ToolController` initialize.

Comment: Explained in more detail in [the documentation for `+[NSObject initialize]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize).

Comment: Ah that makes sense, didn't realize that subclasses were calling it as well.  Mostly I had a hard time forming a google query for `self == [className self]`.  Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

From the Apple Docs on `NSObject` about `initialize`:

> The superclass implementation may be called multiple times if subclasses do not implement initialize—the runtime will call the inherited implementation—or if subclasses explicitly call [super initialize]. If you want to protect yourself from being run multiple times, you can structure your implementation along these lines:

```
+ (void)initialize {
  if (self == [ClassName self]) {
    // ... do the initialization ...
  }
}
```

As you can't assume that *every* subclass will overwrite the `initialize` method (in fact, *most* probably won't), it's best practice to check that the class is actually the one you're expecting.